# How to make angularjs seo

Tags: angularjs, meta-tags, prerender

I am new to angularjs and its seo process, Please can you give me a favour to index all pages in a site.

Prerender pages working good while manual checking with ?_escaped_fragment_= term and also saved in dashboard.

But seo point of view, homepage only got indexed using prerendered html snapshot.Other pages indexed with empty content section, header & footer section only displayed.
​
In header part, i have used

```
<base href="/seo3/">
<meta name="description" content={{description}}>
<meta name="robots" content={{robots}}>
<link rel="canonical" href="{{canonical}}" />
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Homepage indexed properly, but other pages not yet. Please give me the solution to index all pages using prerendered snapshots. I think route action not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

use a service to bind data to `meta` tags

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
     <base href="/seo3/">
     <meta name="description" content={{metaservice.description()}}> 
  </head>


<script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.service('metaservice', function() { 
       return {

          description: function(){ return 'your discription'; }, 
       }
    });

   app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){ 
   });
</script>
```